# How to group data into groups of sizes that correspond to normal distribution

Tags: java, statistics, random, normal-distribution

I want to randomly divide `n` elements into groups. The group sizes should correspond to normal distribution (with given mean and standard deviation)

```
public <T> Collection<Set<T>> group(Collection<T> elements, int numOfGroups) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

public <T> Collection<Set<T>> group(Collection<T> elements, int groupSizeMean, int standardDeviation) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

A fixed mean and standard deviation define a curve on the graph below,

[image: Normal distribution]

<sup>source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution</sup>

I guess in the first case I have to pick `numOfGroups` points on that curve (that divide the x-axis in `numOfGroups + 1` equal segments.

Sum up the function values defined by those points, compute the proportions and use them to derive the individual group sizes from `elements.size()`.

---

**Question**

Is the approach I described viable. What do I have to consider when picking the points on the x-axis. What is a valid range? `mean` with variance (or twice the variance) as tolerance?

---

**Example**

I have 130 Integers and I divide them in groups of following sizes:
10, 15, 20, 20, 25, 40 (which equals 20 - 10, 20 - 5, 20 - 0, 20 + 0, 20 + 5, 20 + 10)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. "The group sizes should correspond to normal distribution" Could you please give a simple example?

Comment: I've added an example and doing this I realized that it's not possible to specify both number of groups and mean + variance.

Comment: "10, 15, 20, 20, 25, 40 " shouldn't the last number be 30? Btw the sum of all these numbers is 130.